# Locator starts on incorrect hostname

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, geode, gfsh

I am running docker image apachegeode/geode:1.9.0 on AWS ec2 instance with Ubuntu 18 AMI. While running gfsh command to start the locator , I see the hostname as garbled. 
How do I set the correct hostname while starting locator so that I can access the locator from Java client ?

gfsh command used is as follows :

```
start locator --name=LocatorOne --log-level=config --J=-Dgemfire.http-service-bind-address=172.17.0.2
```

gfsh start locator command results are as given below :

```
Starting a Geode Locator in /LocatorOne...
.........
Locator in /LocatorOne on b9e7f469d3b9[10334] as LocatorOne is currently online.
Process ID: 40
Uptime: 12 seconds
Geode Version: 1.9.0
Java Version: 1.8.0_201
Log File: /LocatorOne/LocatorOne.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.enable-cluster-configuration=true -Dgemfire.load-cluster-configuration-from-dir=false -Dgemfire.log-level=config -Dgemfire.http-service-bind-address=172.17.0.2 -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: /geode/lib/geode-core-1.9.0.jar:/geode/lib/geode-dependencies.jar

Successfully connected to: JMX Manager [host=b9e7f469d3b9, port=1099]

Cluster configuration service is up and running.
```

The above mentioned garbled hostname appears in Java client code while I try to put a key-value pair to a region.

Answer (score 1):

The `http-service-bind-address` specifies the IP address to which the HTTP service will be bound. What you should be using instead is `hostname-for-clients`, which is basically the host name or IP address that **will be sent to clients so they can connect to this locator**.
Please have a look at the [`start locator`](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/19/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/start.html#topic_591260CF25D64562A0EDD7260D2AC6D4) command for further details.
Best regards.

Comment: I used the following command to start off a locator 
start locator --name=LocatorOne --log-level=config --hostname-for-clients=<<My EC2 public dns>>.  
The logs are as follows 
Starting a Geode Locator in /LocatorOne... ...... 
Locator in /LocatorOne on __95efd853b30e__[10334] as LocatorOne is currently online
...
... 
Successfully connected to: JMX Manager [host=__95efd853b30e__, port=1099] 

As you can see, the host is still not set correctly .

Comment: I've recently worked in [GEODE-5731](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-5731) and couldn't reproduce the problem at all using the latest `develop` version, the `hostname-for-client` property is correctly used and shared with the clients when they request connection information... maybe the `docker image` is somehow screwing things up?.

Comment: @jaun Ramos I ran geode docker image version 1.8.0 and start locator command as __start locator --name=LocatorOne --log-level=config --hostname-for-clients=<<my ec2 public dns>>__ . I see logs as __Locator in /LocatorOne on 1d907025f4bc[10334] as LocatorOne is currently online__ Hence the client is unable to connect to host __1d907025f4bc__. Somehow I fail to set the docker image hostname ...

Comment: I don't know much about `Docker` so, unfortunately, I'm not in a good position to answer... a good test would be to start the locator directly on the `AWS EC2 Instance` **without Docker** and see if things work. If they do, then at least you'll know that the problem is related to the `Docker` image hostname, which might narrow down the scope of the troubleshooting. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I could manage to bring the container up using the below commands __sudo docker run -it --name <<ec2 public dns>> --hostname <<ec2 public dns>> -p 8080:8080 -p 10334:10334  -p 40404:40404 -p 1099:1099 -p 7070:7070 apachegeode/geode:1.9.0

start locator --name=LocatorOne --hostname-for-clients=<<ec2 public dns>> --log-level=config --J='-Dgemfire.jmx-manager-hostname-for-clients=<<ec2 public dns>>'__